# How to sum up all numbers contained in user input from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am searching for an algorithm, which gets user input with a few numbers and then the result should be the sum of all those numbers printed on the console.
I know how to make the list and print it, but I can't select each number and add them together to get a final result.

```
costs = input('Enter the exspenses: ')                                      
costlist = costs.split()                                                    
for each_number in costlist:                                                  
  total = (int(costlist.index(each_number))+1)+                                
  print()
```

I know that something doesn't need to be here and that the total string isn't finished, but I think I'm somewhere close to the solution.

Answer (score 2):

To calculate your total, just use [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) built-in function like this:

```
costs = input('Enter the exspenses: ')
costlist = costs.split()
costlist = [int(i) for i in costlist]
total = sum(costlist)
```

Comment: Or `sum([int(i) for i in costs.split()])`

Comment: You might as well want to check if `i` can be casted to an integer. Depending on the user's input, the program might fail.